# Using Alteryx's Mongo Connection Tool To Connect With A Mongo Labs Database (Collection)

Tags: mongodb, etl

I've been test driving Alteryx for the last week or so and was wondering if anyone has successfully connected to a Mongo Labs data base using the Alteryx Mongo Input and Output tools.  I've tried numerous times and can's seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I am using that MongoDB extractor on a daily basis to generate TDE files to feed Tableau, since Tableau does not offer dedicated extractors, but I admit it was difficult to get started.
Extraction is now swift from a MongoDB running on AWS, make sure you indicate the proper collection, and be aware of one flaw with the current version of extractor, as of Alteryx 9.5: it is missing the flag to send to the DB that would let you read from a Read Only configured MongoDB. It is on the priority list for V10. In the meantime, you should connect to the DB that can be written to, and to ease your DBA, show that Alteryx workflows can't write to it unless you drag into the workflow the MongoDB Output Tool.

Also you can use the Properties / Criteria window to set filters on the indexed field of your MongoDB. After much research, I found out the precise syntax for filtering the extraction by date:
{_id: {$gt: ObjectId("54a4fe800000000000000000")}}

Since each MongoDB ObjectId contains an embedded timestamp of its creation time.
To get the proper time, you can use this excellent website:
http://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/

And if you need fancier filters, here is some help with the syntax:
http://www.querymongo.com/

I hope that helps...